# About the way to modify the list in-place in a function in Python

Tags: python, in-place

If I try to modify the 'board' list in-place in the way below, it doesn't work, it seems like it generate some new 'board' instead of modify in-place.

```
def func(self, board):
    """
    :type board: List[List[str]]
    """
    board = [['A' for j in range(len(board[0]))] for i in range(len(board))]

    return
```

I have to do something like this to modify it in-place, what's the reason? Thanks.

```
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[0])):
            board[i][j] = 'A'
```

Comment: Notice how in your first code sample, the variable name is on the left, and the list on the right. In your second code sample, the list is on the left.

Comment: Does it actually have to modify in-place? Couldn't you just return the new `board` variable, and assign it back to whatever variable held the original?

Comment: If it _does_ have to modify in-place, does only the top-level `board` have to be modified in-place (changing it to a list of brand-new lists), or do the sublists all have to be modified as well?

Comment: @mypetlion  Yes, I have to do it in-place, it is the requirement of an algorithm question :)

Comment: As a side note, do you really want `len(board[0])` instead of `len(board[i])` there? (The answer could well be yes—e.g., the way you've written it ensures that if you somehow get a non-square board, you'll raise an exception. I just wanted to make sure it was intended.)

Answer (score 4):

You seem to understand the difference between these two cases, and want to know why Python makes you handle them differently?

> I have to do something like this to modify it in-place, what's the reason?

---

Creating a new copy is something that has a value. So it makes sense for it to be an expression. In fact, list comprehensions would be useless if they weren't expressions.

Mutating a list in-place isn't something that has a value. So, there's no reason to make it an expression, and in fact, it would be weird to do so. Sure, you *could* come up with some kind of value (like, say, the list being mutated). But that would be at odds with everything else in the design of Python: `spam.append(eggs)` doesn't return `spam`, it returns nothing. `spam = eggs` doesn't have a value. And so on.

---

Secondarily, the comprehension style feeds very well into the iterable paradigm, which is fundamental to Python. For example, notice that you can turn a list comprehension into a generator comprehension (which gives you a lazy iterator over values that are computed on demand) just by changing the `[…]` to `(…)`. What useful equivalent could there be for mutation?

Making the transforming-copy more convenient also encourages people to use a non-mutating style, which often leads to better answers for many problems. When you want to know how to avoid writing three lines of nested statement to mutate some global, the answer is to stop mutating that global and instead pass in a parameter and return the new value.

Also, the syntax was copied from Haskell, where there *is* no mutation.

---

But of course all those "often" and "usually" don't mean "never". Sometimes (unless you're designing a language with no mutation), you need to do things in-place. That's why we have `list.sort` as well as `sorted`. (And a lot of work has gone into optimizing the hell out of `list.sort`; it's not just an afterthought.)

Python doesn't stop you from doing it. It just doesn't bend over *quite* as far to make it easy as it does for copying.

Comment: Thanks for those details, very good points to understand Python more :)

Answer (score 0):

that is not modifying it in place. The list comprehension syntax `[x for y in z]` is creating a new list. The original list is not modified by this syntax. Making the name inside the function point to a new list won't change what list the name outside the function is pointing.

In other words, when calling a function python passes a reference to the object, not the name, so there is no easy way to change which object the variable name outside the function is refering to.

Comment: I see, it is interesting the Python allows two 'board' existing in the same function. Thanks.

Comment: @TG `board` is just a name. It refers to some object. What you do when you use assignment (the `=`) is just make the name `board` point to a different object.

Comment: Python **never** passes parameters by reference.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it always passes by reference. In fact python has no values, only references. All variable names are references.

Comment: @nosklo and yet, it does *not pass by reference*. Indeed, if it did, then assigning to the reference would be seen by the caller. Python uses [call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing), an admittedly esoteric term for a very common evaluation strategy. Passing references as arguments is *not the same thing* as call-by-reference semantics. If it were, you could do something like this in python `def f(&x): x=3` then `b=2;f(b);print(b)` would print `3`, but it doesn't and you can't do that in Python.

Comment: It might be accurate to say that "Python passes by value, where all values are references", but it is certainly incorrect to say it "passes by reference". Most modern languages do not support call by reference. One example is C++, but not C.

Comment: Arguing about whether Python is pass-by-value or pass-by-reference is pointless. You can define the terms to make either one true, and all that you learn from doing so is how you chose to define the terms. Liskov tried to come up with new terminology to solve this problem 40 years ago, and it didn't work for her. The answer is to just stop arguing about names and instead just talk about what actually happens.